# Whats the differece between Item[n]?.MinValue and Item[n].MinValue?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, null-conditional-operator

I would like to add MapWinGis to my C# application ,but I don't know the following:

**Whats the difference between (examples 1 and 2)
and the meaning of the [question mark] in the first sample?**

```
Shapefile.Categories.Item[n]?.MinValue
```

VS

```
Shapefile.Categories.Item[n].MinValue
```

Comment: What is "`MapWinGis`" ?

Comment: The expression `Shapefile.Categories.Item[n]?.MinValue` will evaluate to `Nothing` (aka `null` in C#) if `..Item[n]` is also `Nothing` - but it will throw if `Items[n]` does not exist - while `Shapefile.Categories.Item[n].MinValue` will throw an NRE if `Shapefile.Categories.Item[n]` is `Nothing`.

Comment: @Dai MapWinGis: [link](https://www.mapwindow.org/mapwingis/getting_started.html), This means: **Shapefile.Categories.Item[n]?.MinValue** EQUALS **Shapefile.Categories.Item[n]== null ? null : Shapefile.Categories.Item[n].MinValue** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` symbol is the null-conditional operator. A null-conditional operator applies member access, ?., or element access, ?[], operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns null.

- If `a` evaluates to `null`, the result of `a?.x` or `a?[x]` is `null`.
- If `a` evaluates to non-null, the result of `a?.x` or `a?[x]` is the same
  as the result of `a.x` or `a[x]`, respectively.

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: i prefer to call this null-propagation operator, cause of it actually propagates null value for the whole expression. There is such rule in [code style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0031). In docs probably it also was named as null propagation operator, but changed some time ago.